# Azure shared image gallery versions using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Can you please help me how to list all the image versions available in Azure Shared Image gallery. I tried all the below , but no luck

```
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/shared_image_gallery.html
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/shared_image_version.html
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/shared_image.html
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a way to do this with the default Terraform data resources. [Here](https://github.com/matti/terraform-shell-resource) is a GitHub repo that leverages a null resource to allow you to run commands that can return data. With something like that you could leverage the Azure CLI to return all your images. Here is the [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sig?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sig-list) for the Azure CLI.

Hope this helps.